# Passing JavaScript object to C#

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to create a new row in a table I have hosted in Azure SQL Database. My front end is AngularJS with C# in .NET as the back end. 
Here is my code from the front end passing the object:

```
var insertTicket = function (newTicket) {
    return $http.post("http://localhost:50412/api/tickets", JSON.stringify(newTicket))
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    console.log("Insert Successful");
                    return;
                });
```

And here is my backend code that receives the data and tries to add to the database:

```
[Route("api/tickets")]
public HttpResponseMessage Post(Ticket t)
{
    TicketsRepository.InsertTicket(t);
    HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    return response;
}
```

In TicketRepisitory:

```
public static void InsertTicket(Ticket tick)
{
    var maxID = (from ticket in dataContext.Tickets
                 select ticket.id).Max();
    var tick = new Ticket();
    tick.id = maxID + 1;

    dataContext.Tickets.Add(tick);
    dataContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

And Here is my Ticket class:

```
public partial class Ticket
{
    //Properties
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string customer { get; set; }
    public string barcode { get; set; }
    public string assignedTo { get; set; }
    public string category { get; set; }
    public string importance { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> openDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> dueDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> closedDate { get; set; }
    public string comments { get; set; }
    public string condition { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> workHours { get; set; }

    //Relationships

    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public Employee Employee1 { get; set; }
    public Equipment Equipment { get; set; }

}
```

I think the issue is with Post() expecting a ticket object. I have tried searching for how to receive JSON data and use that for Ticket, but with out much luck.
My Problem is that I can not create a new row. No changes are reflected in my database.

Comment: You don't say what your actual problem is? What do you actually see that's not what you want?

Comment: What are **newTicket** object look like in client side and **Ticket** class look like in server side? Do you see any script error in the browser?

Comment: Have you used a debugger to see what value t is when it's called?  Is it being called at all?  If so is it null or populated with some sort of value?  Make sure the properties of the Ticket class match the json fields in New Ticket

Comment: Sorry my problem is that I am trying to add newTicket to the Tickets table in my database. This is not happening. Everywhere that I look seems to suggest that the way I am trying to add and save the changes in TicketRepository is correct, so I think the issue is with passing the data from client to server.

Comment: What does your Ticket class look like?

Comment: I've added what my Ticket class looks like

Comment: `JSON.stringify(newTicket)` - what does it return? And is your controller method (Post) called when the data is sent?

Comment: This really screams for basic debugging. Put a breakpoint in the first line of Post(). What is `t` at that point? Is it valid? No? Look at the JavaScript. Put a breakpoint in the first line of `insertTicket`. Examine `newTicket`. Is it valid? Yes? You might need to look at the HTTP headers. It may be trying to post using a content type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, which won't work for JSON data, and you'll need to change it to `application/json`.

Comment: ticket = Object {title: "TEST", barcode: "COM-000000002", duedate: Sun Sep 09 2001 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time), category: "troubleshoot" ...}

Comment: JSON.stringify(ticket) = "{"title":"TEST","barcode":"COM-000000002","duedate":"2001-09-09T05:00:00.000Z","category":"troubleshoot","importance":"low","comments":"TESt","username":"hofr"}"

Comment: **newTicket** doesn't match with **Ticket** class. They need to be exactly same. Otherwise, model binder won't be able to bind it.

Comment: You can check for ModelState.IsValid in the post method of controller before saving

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `JSON.stringify` your object when POSTing data with `$http`in AngularJS, just pass the object itself as the second parameter, like this:

```
var insertTicket = function (newTicket) {
return $http.post("http://localhost:50412/api/tickets", newTicket)
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                console.log("Insert Successful");
                return;
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

First there is no need to call JSON.stringify() method on newticket javascript object for second paramter of $http.post() method.

Then in the web api method write a parameter of type JObject with the name newTicket to receive the posted object, and use generic version of ToObject method to convert posted data to desired type. Don't forget to use [FromBody] attribute for the method parameter. the code for webapi looks like this:

```
[Route("api/tickets")]
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]JObject newTicket)
{
    var t = newTicket.ToObject<Ticket>();
    TicketsRepository.InsertTicket(t);
    HttpResponseMessage = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    return response;
}
```